# Strange behavior for includes with conditions in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've had to query some weird database extracted from an excel file, it's pretty bad designed. This has leaded me to some strange needs for the ActiveRecord, one of those is setting conditions when eager loading relations.

So here's my problem and my weird solution.

1.- I include the relation

```
ModelOne.includes(:relation)
```

2.- I try to set conditions on the columns of the included table

```
ModelOne.includes(:relation).where("relation.some_column = something")
```

And I get the following error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column some_column in where clause ...
```

The error, of course, displays the query which contains no joins or something that refers to the included table.

Now, in the other hand, this works:

```
ModelOne.includes(:relation).where(relation: { some_column: "something" })
```

This sintax with hashes it's cool but doesn't support LIKE queries, for example, so... the strange thing is that, after passing a hash including the included table, every reference to the columns of this table works. Let's say, for what I've found, this is how I would do a LIKE query:

```
ModelOne.includes(:relation).where.not(relation: { id: nil }).where("some_column LIKE ?","")
```

Note the weird not where, it does nothing in terms of conditioning the query, but I need it so I can use the columns of the eager loaded table in following methods (LIKE's, groups and so)

What is the right way of doing this? Why does Rails behave like this? What am I doing wrong? When does Rails actually include the eager loaded table?

Note: Using the joins method it's not an option in this case for different reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Read 13.2 Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations

```
Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For
SQL-fragments you need use references to force joined tables:

Article.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible = true").references(:comments)
```